# Do i need to support Facebook Login in my Android app to share users' posts on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-sharer

I am creating an Android app that uses the users' Google Account Credentials for authentication of their email addresses. However, I want to share users' transactions in my app as posts on Facebook. I went through [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/) documentation that Facebook provides for sharing from Android.

From the documentation, it is not clear if it is mandatory to support Facebook Login as an authentication method in my Android app or not. These are the conflicting quotes from the documentation that are creating this confusion for me:

Quote # 1:

> Items can also be shared in two different ways:
>
> - Using the Share Dialog, a built-in dialog that has the Facebook look-and-feel, is very easy to implement, and **doesn't require the user to be logged into your app using Facebook in order to share**.
> - Making API calls, which allows you more control of the sharing user experience but requires that the user is logged into your app using Facebook Login in order to be able to share, and as a result needs more implementation effort.

Quote # 2:

> Before you can share to Facebook from your app, or attempt to follow any of the sharing tutorials, you will need:
>
> - Your environment set up
> - A Facebook app properly configured and linked to your Android app, **with Facebook Login enabled**
> - The Facebook SDK added to your project

So can someone experienced with this please clarify whether implementing a Share Dialog also requires the implementation of Facebook Login in an Android app or not?

Comment: We implement facebook integration with are app two way 1. using native app means try to login,share via device facebook app. 2. using facebook dialog so in 2 way doing any things with facebook done by facebook dialog even if facebook app avilable on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the share dialog, you do not need to implement facebook login. You do, however, need to have a Facebook app ID.